# Browser compatibility mode defaulting to IE5 in my web application

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, compatibility, ie8-compatibility-mode

We have .NET web application which starts with an index.asp. This index.asp contains a lot of iframes inside it and each iframe is loading another HTML file.

The web application compatibility mode should be IE8.

The issue what we are facing is when we open the app in IE, it is setting compatibility mode by default to IE5.

I have tried all the below suggestion mentioned in related posts like

1. Added metadata tag

   `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`
2. Unchecked 'Display intranet sites in compatibility mode' checkbox.
3. Added below setting in web.config in IIS server

   `<httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
           <clear />
           <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>`

But none of them are working and still, it is taking IE5 as default compatibility mode.

Can someone please help. This is really a road blocker for us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one fixed my problem.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```